# Making local timeago

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, timeago

http://timeago.yarp.com/

I can see  different local file of jquery.timeago.js at

https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/tree/master/locales

But i don't know how to use them.

Suppose i want a french version what can i do?

For Jquery date picker it was easier,
i just had to say

```
 " $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['Fr']);"
```

in doumnet.ready.
Buy i don't know how to put that type of a thing here!

Comment: just load the locales you want after timeago library, it'll overcharge the default locales strings

Comment: I want to do that conditionaly.How to do that?

Comment: use javascript to include the script